# Reaching this when http install is done for Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I've tried to simplify question and minimized the code below. What is trying to achieve is calling a callback function when http installation is done. Callback method is being called but `this` variable and its bound variables are not reachable because `this` be undefined when asyn load is done.

```
load(callBackFn)this.http.get(this.sourceAddress).subscribe(
            op =>{     
    if(callbackFn)
    {
       callBackFn();
    }    
}

this.load(function()
 {
    //**THIS IS NULL HERE ? BUT ACTUALLY this.uniqueId is set**
     $('#' + this.uniqueId).css("display", "block");  
})
```

Comment: Something in your code looks mis-indented or something. Can you make sure youre pasting it correctly.

Comment: Maybe try an arrow function? `this.load(() =>
 {
     $('#' + this.uniqueId).css("display", "block");  
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure why you would want to do that way, seems a bit messy with callback functions when you could just access what ever class member you needed after you subscribe, but I guess that you would have to bind the this you wanted to the callback:

```
export class SomeComponent
{
    private sourceAddress = 'some/url';
    private uniqueId = 'spam';


    constructor(private http: Http)
    {
    }

    ngOnInit()
    {
        this.load(this.loadSuccess).bind(this);
    }

    load(callBackFn)
    {
        this.http
            .get(this.sourceAddress)
            .subscribe(
                response =>
                {
                    if (callBackFn)
                    {
                        callBackFn();
                    }
                  this.loadSuccess() //or just call it directly with no callback
                },
                error =>
                {
                    console.log(error)
                });
    }

    loadSuccess()
    {
        $('#' + this.uniqueId).css("display", "block");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks  `bind` did the trick. You wrote that callback is messy. So, what is your alternative? I would like to call a function which use local `uniqueid` property. Did you mean is there another workaround ??

Comment: have updated the answer see comment. Rather than passing callbacks around just access the function you want on the class using `this.loadSuccess()` the simple approach is always the better one.

Comment: thanks got it. It was its initial state. I thought there were an alternative to 'bind' from your word.